# Numpy 2d array, select indices satisfying conditions from 2 arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two 3x3 arrays. One of them indicates if an element is black (let's say 0's - white, 1's black) and another what is the cost of an element. Is there a nice way to get indices of for example all elements that are black and their price is higher than certain value? I know I can use np.where() to select from one array, but how to do it on two (if they have the same shapes)

Comment: For this example, you could sum the arrays and find all instances of 2

Comment: Or `np.where(a & b)`

Comment: That was just an example to illustrate what I want to achieve, I will change it.

Comment: @zlenyk Psidom's comment still holds.  Just change `b` to `b > val`: `np.where(a & (b > val))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on the advice of Psidom and rayryeng, I'll add that the output of `np.where` can be stacked to present a list of indices in the readable "coordinate" notation, as shown below

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(3,3))
b = np.random.uniform(0, 10, size=(3,3))
print(a)
print(b)
print(np.where(a & (b > 4)))
print(np.vstack(np.where(a & (b > 4))).T)
```

Random arrays `a` and `b`:

```
[[1 0 0]
 [1 1 0]
 [0 1 1]]
[[ 4.27082885  4.95718491  5.03538203]
 [ 8.41593579  3.17425233  3.99337567]
 [ 3.90636291  4.96133978  3.61849744]]
```

Direct output of `np.where` for the two conditions `a` nonzero and `b>4`:

```
(array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int64), array([0, 0, 1], dtype=int64))
```

Stacked in a human-friendly way:

```
[[0 0]
 [1 0]
 [2 1]]
```